# Filtering Sub-grid records based on Lookup in MSCRM 2016 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to filter Subgrid based on lookup value in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Online.

[image: image here for explanation]

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend to you is, create a Quick view form on your quote. Inside this QV form insert a sub-grid to show your associated quote-details. After that, go to "groupement" entity form and from "insert" tab - add the Quick View Form you created.

There is another way is customize the grid view but you need to use un-supported javascript.